# Monotouch Dialog: Passing data up the navigation tree

Tags: ios, monotouch.dialog

I was wondering if you could help me with a problem:

Consider the following dialog which contains two screens. The first screen shows a StringElement (called 'address') along with a RootElement which navigates to the second screen which has an EntryElement (called 'searchAddress').

```
RootElement root = new RootElement("Welcome");
StringElement address = new StringElement("Address","");
EntryElement searchAddress = new EntryElement("Enter an address","");

root.Add(new Section(){
     address,
     new RootElement("Search for Address"){
         searchAddress
     }
}
Root = root;
```

**Problem: How do I pass the contents/Value of *searchAddress* (EntryElement) back to *address* (StringElement) on the previous screen?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to implement the Changed event on the EntryElement and then call to Dialog.ReloadData(),something like this:

```
    searchAddress.Changed += (s,e) => {
            address.Value = searchAddress.Value;
            this.ReloadData();
        };
```